# Needed ports for Kubernetes cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes, firewall

Suppose I want to create a k8s cluster on bare metal servers, with 1 master and 2 nodes. What ports do I have to open in my firewall so that the master and nodes can communicate over the Internet? (I know I can just use VPN, but I just want to know which ports I need). I guess I need at least the following ports. Do I need more? How about if I'm using Flannel or Calico? I want to create a *comprehensive* list of all possible k8s services and needed ports. Thank you.

kubectl - 8080

ui - 80 or 443 or 9090

etcd - 2379, 2380

Answer (score 27):

the ports for kubernetes are the following:

[image]

from the CoreOS [docs](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-networking.html).

Comment: does this CoreOS docs' mentioned ports also apply to other Kubernetes implementations e.g. kops, EKS, GKE?

Answer (score 26):

Kubernestes needs:

Master node(s):

```
TCP     6443*       Kubernetes API Server
TCP     2379-2380   etcd server client API
TCP     10250       Kubelet API
TCP     10251       kube-scheduler
TCP     10252       kube-controller-manager
TCP     10255       Read-Only Kubelet API
```

Worker nodes (minions):

```
TCP     10250       Kubelet API
TCP     10255       Read-Only Kubelet API
TCP     30000-32767 NodePort Services
```

Comment: For weave you need 6783/6784 tcp&udp

Comment: Can you please give a link to the source? Thank you!

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports official docs

Comment: These official docs are your best place to get a good list. The 'Used by' column is not above and it could be important if you really want to have a secure system and not just open up ports for everyone. Just too bad the official documentation on this is not that straight-forward to find.

Comment: Oracle says, these ports: https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/olcne/1.1/start/ports.html

Comment: And which ports should be accessible from the public network interface(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Providing that the API server, etcd, scheduler and controller manager run on the same machine, the ports you would need to open publicly in the absence of VPN are:

Master

- 6443 (or 8080 if TLS is disabled)

  Client connections to the API server from nodes (kubelet, kube-proxy, pods) and users (kubectl, ...)

Nodes

- 10250 (insecure by default!)

  Kubelet port, accepts connections from the API server (master).

Also nodes should be able to receive traffic from other nodes and from the master on pretty much any port, on the network fabric used for Kubernetes pods (flannel, weave, calico, ...)

If you expose applications using a NodePort service or Ingress resource, the corresponding ports should also be open on your nodes.

Comment: Thank you. So, you don't need to expose etcd?

Comment: Yes and No: if etcd runs standalone on the same host as the API server it can listen on localhost. If you have a separate cluster for etcd (typically 3 hosts) you should allow traffic from the hosts running the API server(s). Make sure to enable TLS on etcd in that case, since etcd doesn't require any authentication by default.

Comment: Thank you again. So, the nodes basically just need access to the K2s master? And that is true even if I use Flannel or Calico or Weave?

Comment: Edit, sorry, "Enter" posts the comment.
So to clarify, if I have 3 servers, all of them on the Internet. Basically, the only port I need to open is 8080 for K8s?
109.74.199.100 Master >:8080
109.74.199.101 Node 1
109.74.199.102 Node 2

Comment: The master also has to establish a connection to the kubelet on each node as explained in my answer, and the firewall should be pretty much disabled completely on the Kubernetes network (requirements may vary depending on the solution you chose)